# Compare two Time stamps in minutes JS

Tags: javascript, time

Hi I'm using this timestamp:

```
function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}
```

and saving pause time here:

```
localStorage["TmpPause"] = getTimeStamp();
```

than after a while read time and compare:

```
var pauseTime = localStorage["TmpPause"];
    var resumeTime = getTimeStamp();

    var difference = resumeTime.getTime() - pauseTime.getTime(); // This will give difference in milliseconds
    var resultInMinute = Math.round(difference / 60000);

    alert(resultInMinute);
```

at the moment I'm unable to calculate the difference in between 2 dates including time. I'm getting error undefined is not a function resumeTime.getTime() ???

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The format of the "timestamp" does not conform to any in common programming use. Far better to use something that is standardised (such as ISO 8601).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getTimeStamp()` does not return a timestamp (*such irony*), instead it returns a String in this format: `"1/20/2014 19:18:28"`

This is how you get a timestamp in millisecond: `Date.now()`, or even `Date().toString()` (time represented in text).

You should store this instead so that you can reuse it later on by doing:

```
new Date(yourTimestamp);  //this returns the original Date object

(newTimestamp - oldTimestamp)/1000/60   //returns difference in minute
```

Comment: Perfect this is the shortest solution & works - Thanks

Comment: There is no irony, typically [timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) are strings. "1/20/2014 19:18:28" **is** a timestamp. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Date objects have an internal *timevalue* that is milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. You can directly compare two Dates as they are typically coerced to number or string as appropriate, e.g.

```
var d1 = new Date(2014,0,20,12,30,0); // 2014-01-20 12:30:00
var d2 = new Date(2014,0,21,02,30,0); // 2014-01-21 02:30:00

// Difference between d2 and d1 in milliseconds (50400000)
var msDiff = d2 - d1;

// Convert ms to decimal minutes (840)
var minutesDiff = msDiff/60000;

// Convert ms to mintues and seconds (840:0)
var mDiff = (msDiff/60000) | 0;
var sDiff = Math.round((msDiff % 60000) / 1000); 
console.log(mDiff + ':' + sDiff);
```

Time values are widely supported, and since they can also be used to create a Date:

```
var date = new Date(timevalue);
```

they are a common way to exchange values representing particular moments in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getTime method of Date().
Could this help?:

```
$variable1 = (new Date()).getTime();
$variable2 = (new Date()).getTime();

$diff =  $variable2 - $variable1;
```

Comment: There is no Date "class" in javascript.

Comment: @RobG how come there isn't? `new Date()` is something super common in Javascript. Try it out.

Comment: There are no classes in javascript, there is a class syntax, but javascript is just objects created by functions (constructors) with prototype inheritance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`getTimeStamp()` returns a *string* (talk about bad naming...).

You cannot call a non-existing function on that string: `resumeTime.getTime()`.

Why don't you simply store real timestamps?

Comment: Typically [timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) *are* strings. :-)